# iOS UITextView don't localize properly in storyboard

Tags: swift3, storyboard, uitextview

I have a storyboard with some text views on it. When I try to localize the storyboard (creating Storyboard.strings file), all of the UITextViews don't localize at all. UILabels are fine.

My config is as follow: 
1 Base Storyboard file with 2 Storyboard.strings files
[Storyboard Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yeMoj.png)

Storyboard.strings files are ok, its working with UILabels after all:
[Storyboard.strings file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7dLVY.png)

Have you found a solution for this problem?
I'm using Xcode 8.3, Swift 3, iOS 10.

Answer (score 2):

You could just make a IBOutlet in Xcode and set the initial UITextView value in the didSet function.

E.g.

```
@IBOutlet var textView: UITextView {
    didSet {
        textView.text = NSLocalizedString("CUSTOM_LOCALISED_STRING", comment: "Comment.")
    }
}
```

Comment: I pretty much want to have my localization in Storyboard. Your solutions forces me to store some parts of the localization in Localizable.strings.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up with this solution:

In a UIViewController I can access my UITextView-objects and force the localized text from Storyboard.strings to be used.

```
func fixTextViewStoryboardLocalization() {
    guard  storyboard != nil else {
        return // No need to fix it if storyboard is not presented
    }
    let storyboardName = storyboard!.value(forKey: "name") as! String
    for case let textView as UITextView in view.subviews {
        if let ident = textView.restorationIdentifier {
            textView.text = NSLocalizedString("\(ident).text", tableName: storyboardName, bundle: Bundle.main, value: "", comment: "")
        }
    }
}
```

Create a custom MyViewController (pick whatever name you want), call this function in viewDidLoad:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        fixTextViewStoryboardLocalization()
    }
}
```

Make sure the storyboard view controller is from class MyViewController:
[MyViewController custom class in Storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1VQwp.png)

In order the code above to work, I need to set the Restoration ID for each UITextView in my Storyboard:
[UITextView Restoration ID](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bl6mh.png)

Final step - localize the text view in Storyboard.strings:

```
/* Class = "UITextView"; text = "Base text"; ObjectID = "MyTextView-Restoration-ID"; */
"MyTextView-Restoration-ID.text" = "Localized text comes here";
```

This works for all my UITextViews in all my storyboards.